# How to specify multiple configurations in a CMake CONFIG generator expression?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, generator-expression

According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#variable-queries), the `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression evaluates to `1`, if the current configuration is *one of the entries in `cfgs` and `0` otherwise*. But how do I add more than one configuration to the `cfgs`-list?

The following snippet generates an error (*$<CONFIG> expression requires one or zero parameters.*)

```
$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>
```

I tried other separators but without any success. Did I miss something or is there a mistake in the documentation?

I know that I could do something like the following, but it would be easier to read if I could reduce the expression to something as above.

```
$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following `$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>` works for me with `cmake 3.19.4`.

Comment: Wait what? Can you try `TARGET_LINK_OPTIONS(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC <$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:/DEBUG>)`? This produces the error for me, while the version mentioned above works. 

Comment: Handling multiple configs in the generator expression has been introduced in CMake 3.19. What does cmake --version outputs in your case?

Comment: @vre Thanks, that makes total sense! ‍♂️ It outputs 3.18.4, since this is what appears to be shipped with the latest Visual Studio version. If you want to, post this as an answer, I will accept it. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling multiple configs in the `$<CONFIG:cfg>` generator expression has been introduced only recently with CMake 3.19. Versions before only accepted a single configuration argument to the generator expression.